Homeomorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ and convexity
I think this should be true.
Let $\varphi: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be an homeomorphism such that $\varphi(0) = 0$. Then there exists $r < 1$ such that $\varphi(\mathbb{D}_r)$ is convex. $(\mathbb{D}_r = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| \leq r\} )$.
Any ideas?
Edit: If it is false let me lower the conditions a bit. Instead of $\varphi(\mathbb{D}_r)$ being convex, just star-shaped at 0.
Thanks

Sure, take $r = 1$. More seriously, why do you think this is true? What have you tried?

I forgot to add r<1. I have the intuition that this should be true and I need it to prove another theorem.

It's like the homeomorphism doesn't move the point 0, and since its continous the points very close to 0 are moved so little that there is a little disk such that the image is convex.

The statement is false. I think I can construct an explicit counterexample.

Yes, the claim is false.

For diffeomorphisms the answer is positive.
